# Creating an array by using aggregate filter

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I'm try to create a array group by first column emp_no, I have this structure in a mysql table:

```
emp_no|salary|
------+------+
 10001| 60117|
 10001| 62102|
 10001| 66074|
 10001| 66596|
 10001| 66961|
 10001| 71046|
 10001| 74333|
 10001| 75286|
```

In logstash I tried aggregate filter using this configuration:

```
filter {
    aggregate {
    task_id => "%{emp_no}"
    code => "
      map['emp_no'] = event.get('emp_no')
      map['salaries'] ||= []
      map['salaries'] << {'salary' => event.get('salary')}
      event.cancel()
    "
    push_previous_map_as_event => true
    timeout => 3
    }
}
```

But this way I have this output:

```
{
  "emp_no": 10001,
  "salaries": [
    {
      "salary": 60117
    },
    {
      "salary": 62102
    },
    {
      "salary": 66074
    },
    {
      "salary": 66596
    },
    {
      "salary": 66961
    },
    {
      "salary": 71046
    },
    {
      "salary": 74333
    }
  ]
}
```

And I need this output, make an array called salaries that contains only salary values:

```
{
  "emp_no": 10001,
  "salaries": [
    60117,
    62102,
    66074,
    66596,
    66961,
    71046,
    ...,
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
map['salaries'] << {'salary' => event.get('salary')}
```

change this to

```
map['salaries'] << event.get('salary')
```